# Question regarding Testrpc evm_increaseTime and oraclise

Tags: truffle, contract-debugging, testrpc, oracles, dapp-debugging

After creating my contract at t1, which is supposed to be called back from oraclise using Ethereum-bridge at t2. I did a time jump to t2 on testrpc using evm_increaseTime and evm_mine. Yet the callback transition was not considered. How can'I proceed please?knowing that I'm using truffle environment, testrpc, Ethereum-bridge and oraclizeAPI.

This is my constructor :
[image]

This is the callBack function :
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Thomas from [Oraclize](http://oraclize.it) here.

As for your request, when you call oraclize_query specifying a future timestamp or a delay, this is considered as a "real world time" and not as a "blockchain time".

Given that, `evm_increaseTime` won't affect the callback execution in any way.

I hope this helps.

Also, if you need further help, feel free to join our [gitter channel](http://gitter.im/oraclize/ethereum-api).

Comment: Does anyone know how to call `evm_increaseTime` from truffle console? There seems to be no info on the Internet.